# How to add a web form page as a partial view in MVC application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to use the asp:chart control in multiple pages of an MVC application. My pages do have some other content as well. So I want to add an aspx web form page with chart control as a partial view.
I know an html helper is available for chart. But, I don't want to use it as I already have a webform page with asp:chart control. I can just add it.

I searched a lot on the web. I am getting blogs on how to add a webform page with master page in MVC application, but didn't get for web form as a partial view. Can some one give some idea or any link to follow.

My aspx page with chart control

```
<asp:Chart ID="chartMain" runat="server" Height="500px" Width="780px" BackGradientStyle="TopBottom" BackSecondaryColor="White"
            Palette="BrightPastel" BorderColor="Gray" BackColor="#f4f4f4" BorderlineDashStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="4" ImageType="Png">
            <Legends>
                <asp:Legend IsTextAutoFit="False" Name="Default" BackColor="Transparent" Font="Trebuchet MS, 8.25pt, style=Bold"></asp:Legend>
            </Legends>
            <ChartAreas>
            </ChartAreas>
</asp:Chart>
```

& In code behind I am initializing the asp:chart control properties.

```
public partial class AspNetchart : Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object Sender, EventArgs E)
    {
        try
        {
            DrawChart();
            return;
        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {  }
    }

    private void DrawChart()
    {
        try
        {
            // Set the data source
            chartMain.DataSource = ObjChartDetails.ChartDataSource;

            // Add series
            AddSeries();

            // Prepares chart area
            DrawChartArea();
        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {}
    }
}
```

Now I have chart in this aspx page. I just want to render this aspx page as a partial view in my MVC application.

Comment: Why do you want to work through a webform page? It's perfectly possible to render a chart in MVC.

Comment: I have mentioned the reason in my question. 
I know an html helper is available for chart. But, I don't want to use it as I already have a webform page with asp:chart control.
I have around 10 charts with different design, so I don't want to do it again for all 10 charts

Comment: If this could be helpful to you http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/a-webform-view-with-a-razor-layout-in-asp-net-mvc-3

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to render your ASPX page inside MVC Action so you can render the chart inside that.
If so, you can refer following link to do that.

[Webform in MVC](http://vadimdev.blogspot.co.at/2011/01/rendering-aspnet-webform-via-mvc-action.html)

You can use your action you mentioned above and return the content in parent page.
Use `@Html.Action()` for it.

Answer (score 0):

As I know as workaround you can render your ASPX page to string and then include in to your RAZOR page:

Rendering:

```
StringWriter _writer = new StringWriter();
HttpContext.Current.Server.Execute("MyPage.aspx", _writer);

string html = _writer.ToString();
```

Comment: I am getting an exception saying:  "Error executing child request for /MyApp/Mypage.aspx. " at HttpContext.Current.Server.Execute("MyPage.aspx", _writer); line & In details I am getting:  {Cannot evaluate expression because debugging information has been optimized away .}  _writer is not getting the chart control, it just gets __Viewstate